# What are the different ways with which we can dynamically Link a DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dynamic-linking

I want to link a .dll dynamically.
What are the multiple ways to do so?

One way I know, is by using `HMODULE WINAPI LoadLibrary(_In_ LPCTSTR lpFileName)`
function.
Is there any other way?
I am trying to understand the below code:

```
#if defined WIN32
    // We want to define DTE_DLL_EXPORT if we are making
    // a dll, but not if we are making a static library...
    #if defined DTE_STATIC
        #define GFITDTE_ENTRYPT
    #else
        #if defined _GFITDTE_BUILD_
            #define GFITDTE_ENTRYPT __declspec(dllexport)
        #else
            #if defined DTE_IMPORT
                #define GFITDTE_ENTRYPT __declspec(dllimport)
            #else
                #define GFITDTE_ENTRYPT
            #endif
        #endif
    #endif
#else // Not WIN32
```

Can some on explain the above code??

Answer (score 1):

The code shown has nothing to do with `LoadLibrary`. It's typical for header files, which in turn means you're building a DLL that's NOT supposed to be loaded via `LoadLibrary`. Instead, the compiler knows the function prototypes from the header, and the linker uses an *import library* to set up the DLL linking.